# Merge strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables

I want to merge two variable with stings alternately using javascript. What would be an algorithm to accomplish this task?

For example:

```
var a = "abc"
var b = "def"

result = "adbecf"
```

Comment: What part of your code is not working ? Happy to help with fixing your code.

Comment: you want a loop of some kind

Comment: What if the strings are not the same the same length?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to perform the following algorithm:

1. Iterate through string 1
2. For each character, if there is a character in the same position in string 2, replace the original character with both

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
function merge(s, t) {
  return s.split("")
          .map(function(v,i) {
              return t[i] ? v + t[i] : v
          })
          .join("")
}
```

or the more [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) type answer:

```
s=>t=>[...s].map((v,i)=>t[i]?v+t[i]:v).join``
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control) to generate an array from the strings (unicode conscious).

After that, just add a letter from each string until there's no letters left in each. Please note this solution will combine strings of uneven length (`aa`+`bbbb`=`ababbb`)

```js
var a = "abc"
var b = "def"
var d = "foo  bar mañana mañana"

function combineStrings(a,b){
  var c = "";
  a = Array.from(a);
  b = Array.from(b);
  while(a.length > 0 || b.length > 0){
    if(a.length > 0)
      c += a.splice(0,1);
    if(b.length > 0)
      c += b.splice(0,1);
  }
  return c;
}

var test = combineStrings(a,b);
console.log(test);

var test2 = combineStrings(a,d);
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be define the longest string and assigned to *for loop*. Also you have to add *if statments* for strings of uneven length, because you want to ignore *undefined* values of shorter string.

```js
function mergeStrings(s1, s2){

   
  var n = s1.length;
  
  if(s1.length < s2.length){
    n = s2.length;
  }
  
  var string = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(s1[i]){
      string += s1[i];
    }
    if(s2[i]){
      string += s2[i];
    }
  }

  return string;
}

console.log(mergeStrings('ab','lmnap'));
console.log(mergeStrings('abc','def'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are the same length, this will work. If not you'll have to append the rest of the longer string after the loop. You can declare `i` outside of the loop and then use `substr()` to get the end of the longer string.

```js
const a = "abc"
const b = "def"

var res = "";
for (var i = 0;i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  res += a.charAt(i) + b.charAt(i)
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex or array processing and joining do the job:

```js
let a = 'abc';
let b = 'def';
console.log(a.replace(/./g, (c, i) => c + b[i]));        // 'adbecf'
console.log(Array.from(a, (c, i) => c + b[i]).join('')); // 'adbecf'
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can solve this using array spread and reduce. Split each string into an array and merge into one array and then use reduce to generate the merged string.

```
function mergeStrings(a, b) {
    const mergedValues = [
     ...a.split(''),
     ...b.split('')
     ].reduce((values, currentValue) => {
         if (!values.includes(currentValue)) {
             values.push(currentValue);
         }
         return values;
       }, []);

    return Array.from(mergedValues).join('');
}
```

Comment: Please add a more descriptive answer, where you explain why or how this code works. This way the whole community can benefit from your answer.